# dynamically inserting value to array with index

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, array-push

Pushing values to an array caused the index to start with 0 if the index were any other values except starting from 0.

```
$a=array("a"=>"Dog","b"=>"Cat");
array_push($a,"Horse","Bird");
```

this will insert Horse and Bird with index 0 and 1.

Can I insert those values with different index? like

```
speed => Horse
fly => Bird
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, by not using `array_push` at all:

```
$a['speed'] = 'Horse';
$a['fly'] = 'Bird';
```

Comment: yeah!! sometime thinking in a complex way misleads us ;) thanks

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)? It's a great solution for modifying and/or appending data to large arrays.

```
$a = array('a' => 'Dog', 'b' => 'Cat');
$a = array_merge($a, array('speed' => 'Horse', 'fly' => 'Bird'));
var_dump($a);
// Outputs:
// array(4) {
//  ['a']=>
//      string(3) 'Dog'
//  ['b']=>
//      string(3) 'Cat'
//  ['speed']=>
//      string(5) 'Horse'
//  ['fly']=>
//      string(4) 'Bird'
// }
```

From The PHP Group:

> Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values
>   of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the
>   resulting array.
>
> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value
>   for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays
>   contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original
>   value, but will be appended.
>
> Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with
>   incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.